# Schedule Iteration of Webservice Callouts

Tags: apex, batch, webservices, dml, schedulebatch

I have an endpoint I am getting updates from, but the only arguments the end point takes is two date parameters. To keep the heap size down, I am limited to about a date range of three months.

I am then using the response body to update objects.

My issue:

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before
>   calling out

Some research into this issue had resolutions utilizing actionFunctions and onComplete's but then I believe I would not be able to schedule this. Another solution to a similar problem was adding the @future method, but then I end up with an error that `future methods cannot be called from future methods.`

Scheduler Class:

```
public class getAccountUpdatesScheduler implements Schedulable{

    public void execute (SchedulableContext SC)
    {
      getAccountUpdatesfromEndpoint.GetAccountUpdatesEndpoint();
    }
}
```

getAccountUpdatesfromEndpoint Class:

```
public class getAccountUpdatesfromEndpoint {

@future(callout=true)
public static void GetAccountUpdatesEndpoint(){

Datetime now = Datetime.now();
integer monthIter = 20; 
string jsonstr = '';
List<Custom_Object__c> accList = new list<Custom_Object__c>();

for(integer i = 0; i < monthIter; i++) {
     datetime endtimedatetime = now.addDays(-3*(dayIterCount-1)); 
    string endtime = endtimedatetime.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
     datetime starttime = now.addMonths(-3*i); 
     system.debug('starttime: ' + starttime);

     HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
     .....

     try {
         .....
         jsonStr = res.getbody();             
         JSONConvertEndpoint endpointGet = (JSONConvertEndPoint)JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, JSONConvertEndPoint.class);

         for(integer i=0; i < endPointGet.size(); i++) {
             Custom_Object__c acc = new Custom_Object__c();
             acc.Field__c = endPointGet[i].field;
             accList.add(acc);
         }

         upsert accList;


     }

   catch {
          /* exception logging */
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please try with batch you can call another batch from a batch

Comment: You can use a queueable.. That error you're getting is something else

Comment: @EricSSH , queueable kind of makes sense. So I would schedule a class that executes my "for" class that iterates my date ranges and sends each iteration to a queueable class to handle the web service callout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting that Uncommitted work error is because you are trying to upsert your `accList` and then doing another call out (move that upsert out of the `for` loop).  In your comments we talked about a queueable would work for this so if you want to go that route read up on queueables and possibly ask another question..

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

Comment: See the following new post: [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216342/queueable-callout-not-allowed-from-this-future-method)

Continuing to encounter different, but future related errors.

Comment: Accept this one if you're moving on to the next one please